# I don't understand where I made a mistake

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I tried this code after documenting myself :

```
struct person
{
    int a;
    char s;
};
struct person test;
test.a = 12;
```

And Code::Blocks returns this following error :

> error: 'test' does not name a type

Can someone explain this error to me? I found this sample code on the internet! I don't understand my mistake.

Thanks for reading, have a nice day.

Comment: I have to add that I tried too without success : "person test; test.a = 12"

Comment: Where is your `main()`?

Comment: You can [edit] your question to clarify things. In any case, you can't make assignments outside of functions, which is your mistake. If that's not it, extract a [mcve]. Also, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I have a hunch this is the [mcve]... He/she/they do not know that these statements should go in a function body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your code work you need to put it in a function and there should be a main function too.

```
struct person
{
    int a;
    char s;
};

int main() // you need to have a main 
{
    // code needs to be in a function

    /*struct*/ person test; // struct is not needed 
    test.a = 12;

    return 0;
}
```